# Travelling Sales Person - Evolutionary Algorithm

Tags: genetic-algorithm, traveling-salesman, evolutionary-algorithm

I have an understanding of how evolutionary algorithms work. I have written one to find the maximum of an equation in n-dimensional space.

I can see a problem using the same design to solve the TSM problem.
When I use cross over, or even mutation, I might create an individual that goes to the same city twice, or doesn't visit every city.

What steps can I take to make sure each individual in my population visits every city only once? That is, every individual is a valid answer.

Comment: You can address it in your scoring function which might give a very low score to someone who visits the same city twice or doesn't visit all of the cities.

Comment: I'd daresay that this question is too broad to be answered here. Please, refine your question. First, you are not speaking of a particular language. Then, it seems that you don't have an understanding of what lists, arrays or other structures common in many languages are. Please, refine your question.

Comment: Use appropriate data structures to track visited cities and perform appropriate comparisons? As others have said, your question as currently stated seems too vague to be answerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the same design pattern which is used to find the maximum of an equation and apply it to TSP problem. The reason is that the chromosome encoding / decoding is different between two problems.
For numeric equation problem, mostly the chromosome can be decoded as "real value" / "binary value" depending on the type of your problem. However, for TSP problem, we have to use the "permutation" encoding. This permutation encoding is mainly used for "Combinatorial optimization" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_optimization)

Below is quite a good reference site for techniques in encoding in GA:
http://www.obitko.com/tutorials/genetic-algorithms/encoding.php

The idea behind this "permutation encoding/decoding" is that: Given a list of n city denoted as c1, c2, ..., cn; the chromosome will be encoded as the order of these cities where the travel salesman has traveled to one by one (e.g. chromosome = c1, c2, ..., cn). By apply permutation on this chromosome, you can generate different chromosomes for the population and GA operators will start from here. Having the chromosome encoded like this can help you to avoid the problem where one city is visited more than once!

Since you do not mention any data structure or preferred programming language, so I cannot post the source code here. If you still want to have some example of working version, you can contact me via email.

Answer (score 0):

A common technique to solve this problem is to impose a "penalty", wherein, any chromosome that have any city that not visited, have a penalty added. For example if a chromosome have five city that not visited, add 5x penalty to chromosome fitness score. In this case any chromosome that have not visited city, gradually Remove from population and permitting other (that have zero no visited city) individuals to be maintained in the population.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use a Double Point Ordered crossover. This type of crossover creates a child from a single parent. Two parents are selected and two random points along the chromosome are selected. The genes between the points are passed to the child. The remaining genes are transferred from the same parent, but in the order that they appear in the second parent. The result is that the child contains all of the values from a single parent but includes ordering, and therefore traits, from both parents.

Two examples of solving the TSP using this type of operator are shown here;

http://johnnewcombe.net/blog/gaf-part-4/

http://johnnewcombe.net/blog/gaf-part-7/

The first of these examples uses an integer to reference the city, the second example simplifies this by using an object based gene to store the city within the chromosome.